# ffmpeg & ffprobe & libfdk-aac on Ubuntu 14.10 server

Tags: command-line, server, 14.10, ffmpeg

**How to install properly ffmpeg?** (*not a duplicate* as most of the similar answers don't work properly)

Normally i compile ffmpeg manually with the following guide

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

leaving out the desktop libs ending up having something like that

(the guide worked perfectly on both 12.04 server & 13.10 desk, NOT on 14.10)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libfreetype6-dev libgpac-dev libtheora-dev libtool libvorbis-dev pkg-config texi2html zlib1g-dev
mkdir ~/ffmpeg_sources
sudo apt-get install yasm
sudo apt-get install libx264-dev
sudo apt-get install unzip
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget -O fdk-aac.zip https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac/zipball/master
unzip fdk-aac.zip
cd mstorsjo-fdk-aac*
autoreconf -fiv
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared
make
make install
make distclean
sudo apt-get install libmp3lame-dev
sudo apt-get install libopus-dev
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://webm.googlecode.com/files/libvpx-v1.3.0.tar.bz2
tar xjvf libvpx-v1.3.0.tar.bz2
cd libvpx-v1.3.0
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-examples
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" make
make install
make clean
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" make
make install
make distclean
hash -r
echo "MANPATH_MAP $HOME/bin $HOME/ffmpeg_build/share/man" >> ~/.manpath
. ~/.profile
```

i reinstalled the NEW(was using 12.04) ubuntu 14.10 server 3 times. but i could not get it to work.
now i'm testing on a virtual machine and it does not work.

i can't find ffmpeg nor ffprobe.

it simply does not work... **i need ffprobe to output json & libfdk-aac**

so i googled and found sam's repo

```
sudo apt-get-repository ppa:samrog131/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get-install ffmpeg-real
```

create links

```
sudo ls -sf /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg
sudo ls -sf /opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe /usr/bin/ffprobe //works but NO OUTPUT
```

the ffmpeg works but i have **no output from ffprobe**. looks like it's not complete...

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams INPUT
```

ffprobe unrecognized command....

**How i could properly install ffmpeg with all it's sub apps like ffprobe & all the necessary codecs like libfdk-aac & ogg on Ubuntu 14.10 Server 64 bit?**

note1: i'm using ffprobe to read the stream info and based on that php/js creates a custom command based on the streams.

note2: i convert my old cameras clips to the now standard multimedia format. (mp4/h264/aac) so m4v just copy the streams, mjpeg is converted, m2ts convert audio ac3 to aac & copy video stream and so on so i prefer libfdk-aac.

note3:with ubuntu 12.04 server i had no direct linkis to the ffmpeg i had to write down the whole path. would be nice to be able to just write ffmpeg or ffprobe.

**UPDATE**

mc3man/trusty-media appears to be the one that is updated & everything works on 14.04 except that it installs extra libs that are totally useless as i'm using a headless server.
libsdl1.2-dev libva-dev libvdpau-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev and so enables also --enable-x11grab

**Is there a way to omit this libs using this repo?
Or can i remove them after the install completely?**

14.04

samrog131/ppa

1. ffprobe does not work ... no output
2. ffmpeg works and libs are included
3. installs extra desktop version libs that are not necessary

mc3man/trusty-media

1. ffprobe works
2. ffmpeg works
3. installs extra desktop version libs that are not necessary

jon-severinsson/ffmpeg

1. ffprobe works
2. very old version of ffmpeg & is missing important libs
3. installs extra desktop version libs that are not necessary

14.10

samrog131/ppa

1. ffprobe does not work ... no output
2. ffmpeg works and libs are included
3. installs extra desktop version libs that are not necessary

mc3man/trusty-media

won't fetch can't install ffmpeg

jon-severinsson/ffmpeg

1. ffprobe works
2. very old version of ffmpeg & is missing important libs
3. installs extra desktop version libs that are not necessary

**UPDATE2**

**READ THE QUESTION**

**I'm on a server , a headless server. NO x11 libs NO Desktop stuff no ffplay**

**14.10** or **14.04**

ffmpeg needs to work

ffprobe needs to work

libfdk_aac

latest versions

the best would be if someone could just tell me what i should change in the compilation guide!

Comment: The http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/ffmpeg-returns-to-official-ubuntu.html has a link to the backported ffmpeg. The link: https://launchpad.net/~kirillshkrogalev/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-next

Comment: sudo apt-get-repository ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get-install ffmpeg
that would work?

Comment: and then create the links?

Comment: The ffmpeg-next is installing to the /usr/bin/

Comment: "Does not work" is impossible to provide help. Please provide detailed information explaining what exactly does not work.

Comment: the installation gives alot more errors while installing ffmpeg. and at the end i could not find the binary ... with various search commands i used like find & other ways. it somehow does not install ffmpeg.

Comment: there is prolly something new in 14.10 wich does not accep the compilation commands i use..

Comment: What are the actual errors?

Comment: like i said i reinstalled it 3 times on a physical mashine and reformatted everything. i have no errors to show you ... i actually was thinking it was my fault ... but not it also does not work on a virtual mashine. samhe here.... i just finished to install a new fresh 14.10 in virtualbox

Comment: I guess I'll have to download 14.10 and give it a try.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~kirillshkrogalev/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-next i see this one has x265 and no other libs are you shure it contains x264 & libfdk-aac @user26687??

Comment: btw if you download it i just noticed that i'm using the wrong version... i should dl the LTS so 14.04 server

Comment: That ppa does not include fdkaac. You could post your issues here & we'll see if a self build can be fixed - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095 A self build is your best option due to server. I have ffmpeg shared for both 14.04 & 15.04 in ppa's with fdkaac, not that inclined to do 14.10. (- though if you wish to discuss in Ubuntu forums maybe I'll put up a server version in a tmp ppa.Ex. of 14.04 - https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/testing6 15.04 - https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-test1 Over time both will get more sources built of off, ect.

Comment: it's ok i can install 14.04.. if there is a ppa without the useless x11 libs and containing the libfdk_aac i would be very happy.

Comment: btw all the test installs where made on a fresh ubuntu install with ssh smg lamp

Answer (score 1):

http://ffmpeg.org/download.html says that there are 2 PPAs.

This one provides static binaries:
https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media

And this one dynamically built ones:
https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg

Comment: sorry but i'm not that good in adding binaries. most of the time i use apt-get install... or read tutorials... can you pls add a terminal command how to install that... And are you shure those contain the real ffmpeg 2.4.3 & ffprobe & libfdk-aac? as i think i already tried the json-serverson ppa but got an error.

Comment: It's exactly that: You add a PPA to your system and then do `apt-get instal ...` Read here on how to add a PPA: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: ok i try it out.. give me some time pls.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg is ffmpeg 1.6 .... i need 2.4.3

Comment: and the first one states that you should stay on 14.04 & or not upgrade

Comment: Try https://launchpad.net/~kirillshkrogalev/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-next then...

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~kirillshkrogalev/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-next installs alot of desktop stuff that is not needed... and also missed some libs.. the only one that is working but also installs alot of useless stuff is the mc3man's repo (like the libfdk_aac)... but it works only on the 14.04 version wich is ok... now i just have to understand if there is also a possibility to install the server version without the extra stuff...or remove the extra unnecessary libraries..

Comment: All of the links ... wich i could simply google don't contain a working ffmpeg with the proper libs &/or contain desktop libs that are useless. Please read the whole question and don't just post the first links you find in google.

Answer (score 0):

There is a statically compiled version of ffmpeg (https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux), it's a portable version :-D

You can download the static builds from http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg

Once downloaded, you can just unpack the .tar.xz file to /opt/ffmpeg for example and make a symlink to /opt/.../ffmpeg executable file and enjoy your ffmpeg :-)

Comment: do this static builds contain the libfdk_aac & what about the x11 libs?

Comment: All of the links ... wich i could simply google don't contain a working ffmpeg with the proper libs &/or contain desktop libs that are useless. Please read the whole question and don't just post the first links you find in google.